# How to define views on top of Excel data table

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with a data table. It has more than 200 columns and around 2000 rows. Different people use the sheet and have different columns in focus for different analysis.

What I want to achieve is to have some sort of capability for defining views on that sheet. Is there an easy, end user friendly way to define views on the master data table.

For example, I should be able to define like this

- Analysis 1 => View 1 = Column A, B, C, X, Y, Z
- Analysis 2 => View 2 = Column D, E, K, X, Y, Z
- Analysis 3 => View 3 = Column A, B, M, P, Q,R,Y, Z

Is there a simple way of doing this. I have been thinking of doing it programatically with VBA and putting a form with buttons on it for each View. But there are two problems with that, first the development requires me to make everyone use a macro enabled sheet which is a pain to get approval from IT, and then secondly the maintenance of these views will probably need someone to go through the code again and get the IT approval each time there is a change/addition of a view.

I am not sure, if I am asking too much from Excel, Is there a solution for this type of scenario.

Comment: Power Query or Get & Transform.

Comment: Do people just look at the data? Then use reporting tools like BigBen suggest. Or do they need to edit data?

Comment: They just view and do some filtering on the data.

Comment: @BigBen Power Query is a good option but the problem is that it only deals with the cell values not the formatting. So for example, if the cells are highlighted red or green its not easy to grab those columns and spit the same with formatting out. Also the number of views created on data is large (around 50) so if I create a query for each and load them in different sheets of the workbook, the size of the workbook suddenly goes up and it becomes heavy to be distributed/used across 20 people.